# How to block website access using squid

Tags: squid, access-control-list

I would like to block black listed URLs and Domains using the squid proxy server.
In the tutorials, what is mostly shown how to block one URL/Domain, however I would like to have the URLs/Domains in a file and have one acl on the config file so that when it comes to updating the list, I just change the file instead of the config file

how can i go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what otheres have suggested, Squid can be [configured](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_peer/) to talk to other proxy servers either as parents or peers. You can use a filtering proxy alongside squid to block the sites that you want to block. You can search for examples of squid+privoxy or squid+dansguardian.

Answer (score 2):

As the list grows the performance drops off quite significantly in my experience.  If you're beyond a few dozen entries I'd suggest you look at [SquidGuard](http://www.squidguard.org/) as an alternative way of blocking entries on that list.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer here

[ACL parameters in an external file.](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#I_want_to_put_ACL_parameters_in_an_external_file.)

Comment: That's a crappy way to solve the problem (and you should flag the question as answered if you have a solution - albeit the wrong one). The right way to solve the problem is via the URL rewriter - not ACLs